# how to fix : bad numeric config value '=' for 'core.logallrefupdates': invalid unit

Tags: git

When I try to run any git command i get this error:  `bad numeric config value '=' for 'core.logallrefupdates': invalid unit.` I do not know how to fix it... is there a command to reset everything ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run :

```
git config --show-origin core.logallrefupdates
```

This will list the file from which this configuration setting is set.

Confirm that you see a faulty value, and edit that file to fix the problem.